# Регулярное выражение: как получить из UserAgent`а версию Андроид?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть несколько примеров UserAgent`ов:

> 1) mozilla/5.0 (linux; android 6.0.1; nexus 5x build/mmb29p)
>   applewebkit/537.36 (khtml, like gecko) chrome/41.0.2272.96 mobile
>   safari/537.36 (compatible; googlebot/2.1;
>   +http://www.google.com/bot.html)
>
> 2) mozilla/5.0 (linux; android 5.0; sm-g900p build/lrx21t)
>   applewebkit/537.36 (khtml, like gecko)
>   chrome/81.0.4044.122 mobile safari/537.36
>
> 3) mozilla/5.0 (linux;
>   android 8.0; pixel 2 build/opd3.170816.012) applewebkit/537.36 (khtml,
>   like gecko) chrome/81.0.4044.122 mobile safari/537.36
>
> 4) mozilla/5.0
>   (linux; android 10; nokia 7.2) applewebkit/537.36 (khtml, like gecko)
>   chrome/81.0.4044.117 mobile safari/537.36

Для функции `preg_match` нужно написать регулярку получения версии Андроид для каждой из вышеуказанных записей. Например, "6.0.1", "5.0" и т.д.
Сам я пришёл к вот такой регулярке: `/android\s(\d.+);/`

Всё ок, но в случае с примером 1 возвращается строка:

> android 6.0.1; nexus 5x build/mmb29p) applewebkit/537.36 (khtml, like
>   gecko) chrome/41.0.2272.96 mobile safari/537.36 (compatible;
>   googlebot/2.1;

Прошу вашей помощи, в регулярках я не очень силён.

Comment: Может, `/android\s+(\d[\d.]*)/`? `/android\s+\K\d[\d.]*/`?

Comment: [`~android\s+\K\d+(?:\.\d)*~`](https://regex101.com/r/bGXf4E/2)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ваш второй вариант подошёл. Спасибо!

Comment: @Эдуард, ваш вариант, также подошёл. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте

```
/android\s+\K\d[\d.]*/
```

См. [пример работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/3dgPtn/1).

**Подробности**

- `android` - строка `android`
- `\s+` - 1 и более пробельных символов
- `\K` - оператор, очищающий буфер текущего совпадения
- `\d` - 1 цифра
- `[\d.]*` - 0 и более цифр и/или символов `.`